# Multi-index search solution idea with autocomplete

Tags: 7, ajax, search

For sometime I have been looking for a complete solution for search capabilities in drupal 7, but there is always some problem. With all the greatness and flexibility of drupal, I have to say that there are some limitations, which are obviously irritating.

For example, if I use [multi-index search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_multi) or any other similar module, the autocomplete feature does not work. I have also tried [custom search module](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search). Idea is to have a drop down with the search box and when someone selects an option and types something in the search bar/box, it should only search the selected option and also have auto-complete feature.

Secondly, I would like to know how to show any search bar/box anywhere on the website. For example, currently I am using following code, I read on this website, to show the search bar on the top of my website. I pasted this in my theme's page.tpl file. This code I am using for the default search provided by drupal. Obviously, when I modify search or use a module, it will have its separate search box and I would want to show it on the top instead of the default search box.

```
<?php
  $block = module_invoke('search', 'block_view', 'search');
  print render($block); 
                ?>
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to post second question separately. Regarding the first one - I work with Search API quite a lot lately and I think it would require custom coding.

Comment: Ragarding the second part: You didn't mention, whether you want to use Search API Views integration or something like https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_page

Comment: I am not sure, but I would prefer anything easy and flexible

Comment: The more flexible is definitely https://www.drupal.org/node/1597930 Please try it and ask again if needed.

Comment: I will try it and let you know